# Find the density function of $X$, from the random vector $(X,Y)$ if the PDF of this vector is:

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

$$\phi(x,y)= \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{8 \pi}}e^{-|x|- \frac{1}{2}x^2y^2}, x,y \in R $$

Now I'm aware I would have to do $$\phi_X(x)=\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}\phi(x,y) dy$$, what is confusing me is this absolute value of x, which makes it difficult to integrate..

Comment: You can put them out of the integral, as they don't depend on $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{8 \pi}}e^{-|x|- \frac{1}{2}x^2y^2} ~dy=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{8 \pi}}e^{-|x|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{- \frac{1}{2}x^2y^2}~dy$$
So there is no problem of absolute value.

Comment: What would I do if say in the exponent i have instead of $- \frac{1}{2}x^2y^2$ say $- \frac{1}{2}|x|y^2$

Comment: Divide the integral into two and sum ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Observe that $x^2$ or $|x|$ is independent of $y$. So, with respect to $y$ they are constants.So, proceed simply. You will not face any problem.